# How to handle close/unavailable endpoint in cxf/camel Producer Template

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I want to send retries if the endpoint I'm sending a request is close or unavailable. I have this code which produces an exception when the endpoint is close:

```
    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    Exchange exchange = template.request(someCloseEndpoint, someProcessor)

    if(exchange.getExcpetion == null) 
       //do something
    else
       //error handling
       //do some retries if close connection
```

When endpoint is close, I see this exception in my log

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Connection refused
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:220) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:174) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
...
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection refused
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:255) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:215) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

But the code above still enters in `if(exchange.getException == null)` instead of the else part for error handling. I also tried wrapping the code in a try-catch statement but I still cant catch any errors.

```
try{
    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    Exchange exchange = template.request(someCloseEndpoint, someProcessor)

    if(exchange.getExcpetion == null) 
       //do something
    else
       //error handling
       //do some retries if close connection
 } catch ( org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault e) {
      // do retries
 } catch ( Exception e) {
      // try catching generic Error for testing purposes
 }
```

Even catch for generic exception does not get anything. How can I handle this close/unvailable endpoint so I can implement retries

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

fault error messages are classified as irrecoverable errors as it is not thrown back to camel by default. In order to capture this , you need to enable fault handling in the camel context.

`getContext().setHandleFault(true);`

```
from("<END_POINT>").handlefault()
```

This will enable the fault to be converted as an Exception. Following this hopefully your code might work.